# Fullpage.js Scroll Overflow not working when horizontal slider added

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js on my site.  I have several pages that are long and have added scrollOverflow: true to make those pages fully scrollable.  That works great until I incorporate a horizontal slider, then the scrollOverflow stops working.  I know that it is possible to have a page that uses scrollOverflow and horizontal sliders because Alvaro demos it on his site (http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#secondPage), but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here's a simple example, where you can't scroll to the bottom of the second green box on page 1; it instead flows onto page 2:

```
<div id="fullpage">

<div class="section">
   <div id="clients">
        <div id="logosTop"></div>

        <div id="logosBottom"></div>

        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide">Text here</div>
            <div class="slide">Text here</div>
            <div class="slide">Text here</div>
            <div class="slide">Text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">Some section</div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage( {
scrollOverflow: true,
verticalCentered: false,
});
});
```

CSS:

```
#clients {
position: relative;
width: 750px;
height: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -375px;
}


#logosTop {
background-color:#096;
width: 1025px;
height: 235px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: -137px;
}

#logosBottom {
background-color:#096;
width: 1025px;
height: 340px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 715px;
margin-left: -137px;
}

#slider {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 450px;
width: 740px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.slide {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 450px;
    width: 740px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Be careful there. You are playing with `absolute` positions and as that moves them out of the page structure and fullPage.js won't be able to detect the height of your slide content.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using relative positioning and giving all the divs defined heights, but it didn't change anything.  If the content is taller than the browser window, I still can't scroll to the bottom of the content.  If I take out the horizontal slider, it works fine.  When I add it back in, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but you will have to provide a reproduction the problem in jsfiddle or add a link to your site if you want us to know what's going on.

Comment: Here is the site: 
www.backstories.tv/indexAlt.html
The page I'm having trouble with is the one called "clients"